# Count the number of occurrences in an array with random numbers without methods or list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I am trying to solve an exercise in C# as follows:

**Write a program that generates 20 random integers between 0 and 9 and displays the count for each number.
Use an array of ten integers, say counts, to store the counts for the number of 0s, 1s, ..., 9s.)**

This is what i come up with which kind of work but i have a problem with the 0's counting 1 extra all the time.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ArrayExercises
{
    class TaskFive
    {
        public static void FindNumberCount()
        {

            int c0=0,c1=02,c2=0,c3=0,c4=0,c5=0,c6=0,c7=0,c8=0,c9=0;
            int[] arr = new int[20];
            Random rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Numbers generated ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = rand.Next(0, 10);
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }
            foreach(int number in arr)
            {
                 if (number == 0) { c0++; }
            else if (number == 1) { c1++; }
            else if (number == 2) { c2++; }
            else if (number == 3) { c3++; }
            else if (number == 4) { c4++; }
            else if (number == 5) { c5++; }
            else if (number == 6) { c6++; }
            else if (number == 7) { c7++; }
            else if (number == 8) { c8++; }
            else if (number == 9) { c9++; }

            }
            Console.WriteLine
            (
              $"Number of 0's: {c0} \n" +
              $"Number of 1's: {c1} \n" +
              $"Number of 2's: {c2} \n" +
              $"Number of 3's: {c3} \n" +
              $"Number of 4's: {c4} \n" +
              $"Number of 5's: {c5} \n" +
              $"Number of 6's: {c6} \n" +
              $"Number of 7's: {c7} \n" +
              $"Number of 8's: {c8} \n" +
              $"Number of 9's: {c9}"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: 1. Why c1=02? 2. Your solution is not what you was asked: "Use an array of ten integers, say counts, to store the counts...."

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten it like this

```
    public static void FindNumberCount()
    {
        int[] count = new int[10];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand.Next(0, 10);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            count[arr[i]]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < count.Length; i++)
        {
                Console.WriteLine($"Number of {i}'s: {count[i]}");

        }
       
    }
```

If you want draw 20 numbers you should for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) not 19.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] counts = new int[10];
int[] numbers = new int[20];


var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{        
    // Generate random numbers
    numbers[i] = random.Next(0, 9);
    // Increment the count of the generated number
    counts[numbers[i]]++;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thanks a million 

Answer (score 0):

the for loop you use loops only 19 times.
You must change the "i < 19" to "i < 20".
In your program, the for loop leaves the last int in the array at it's default value (0),
this also explains, why you always have one more zero.
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is in this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
```

You initialized an array with 20 int and set only value to 19 of them.
If you don't set the value int defaults to Zero and hence you always get one extra zero
Change your code as below

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks Ansil, that showed me the logic behind my mistake. I learned something there 

Answer (score 0):

The halting condition of the first for loop should be **i<20**. Then your program should work.

This is how I would solve it:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Random random = new Random();

     //Fill array with random numbers
     int[] array = new int[20];
     for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
         array[i] = random.Next(0, 10);

     //Count how many times a number occurs
     int[] numberCounts = new int[10];
     for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
         numberCounts[array[i]]++;

     //Print the count of the numbers
     for(int i = 0; i < numberCounts.Length; i++)
         Console.WriteLine("Number of " + i + "'s: " + numberCounts[i]);

     //Keep the console open
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Comment: That was very details from you Henrik. Thank you very much 